# Export GPX file from Leaflet

Tags: export, leaflet, geojson, gpx

What I want to do is let the users create a GPX file by selecting some GeoJson features in Leaflet. The way in which I'm doing it is by creating a new GeoJson layer to store the selected features, then converting this to gpx with a plugin called togpx (https://github.com/tyrasd/togpx). Now I have a gpx file, but I don't know how can I let the users download it. Any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
var GPXfile;
var trails = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/trasee.geojson', {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            click: function () {
                var selectedGeojson = {
                  "type": "FeatureCollection",
                  "features": [
                    {
                      "type": "Feature",
                      "properties": {
                       "name": "Rocka Rolla"
                      },
                      "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": feature.geometry.coordinates
                      }
                    }]
                }
                GPXfile = togpx(selectedGeojson);
            }
        })
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

A JsFiddle might help: http://jsfiddle.net/pufanalexandru/20ara4qe/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that ...

A link to trigger the dowload:

```
<a href="#" download="MyTracks.gpx" id="exportGPX">Export to file</a>
```

Some javascript (you have to include jquery):

```
$("#exportGPX").on('click', function (event) {

        // prepare the string that is going to go into the href attribute
        // data:mimetype;encoding,string
        data = 'data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(gpxData);

        // set attributes href and target in the <a> element (with id  exportGPX)
        $(this).attr({
            'href': data,
            'target': '_blank'
        });

        // let the click go through
    });
```

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/vxe23py4/

Note: it works with Chrome, but you should try other browsers too.

Comment: Works like a charm, but, considering I'm a Javascript noob, could you explain this part of the code to me, please: 'data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(gpxData); Or just give me a link where I can read about it

Comment: The goal is to edit href and target attributes before letting the click be processed. In the href attribute, you can put some data ( data:mimetype;encoding,string). The string is escaped using encodeURIComponent function